# Regex split position before and after match

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to split a string using PHP `preg_split` that contains tags in the form `[fbes_keep]...[/fbes_keep]`.

The regex I have is `(?=\[\/?fbes_(remove|keep)])` ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/iiJBlq/1))

My input is

```
[fbes_keep]hello[/fbes_keep][fbes_remove]goodbye[/fbes_remove]
```

The code I'm using is `$fragments = preg_split( '@(?=\[\/?fbes_(remove|keep)])@i', $original );`

What I want is for the splits to be like this: (where a `|` character is a split, with added spaces for readability)

```
[fbes_keep] | hello | [/fbes_keep] | [fbes_remove] | goodbye | [/fbes_remove]
```

But the splits I'm getting are:

```
[fbes_keep]hello | [/fbes_keep] | [fbes_remove]goodbye | [/fbes_remove]
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$var = explode("|", $myString);`?

you're trying to get the " hello " and " goodbye " values, right?

Comment: The `|`s aren't in the original, they're only in the example for demonstration purposes. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: try `preg_match("'[fbes_keep](.*?)[/fbes_keep]'si",$result,$original);`

Comment: Your regex, with slight modifications, works, but how would I iterate over them? I want to process the fragments one at a time. (For completeness, modified regex: `(\[fbes_(?:keep|remove)])(.*?)(\[/fbes_(?:keep|remove)])`)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach with `preg_match_all` and `implode` functions:

```
$str = '[fbes_keep]hello[/fbes_keep][fbes_remove]goodbye[/fbes_remove]';
preg_match_all("/\[\/?[a-z_]+\]|[a-z]+\b/", $str, $matches);
$result = implode(" | ", $matches[0]);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
[fbes_keep] | hello | [/fbes_keep] | [fbes_remove] | goodbye | [/fbes_remove]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match_all and loop over the matches for more organization and flexibility in using the results:

```
   $str = '[fbes_keep]hello[/fbes_keep][fbes_remove]goodbye[/fbes_remove]';
    preg_match_all('@([[][^]]*[]])([^[]*)([[]/[^]]*[]])@Ui', $str, $matches);

    /*
    // die('<pre>'.print_r($matches,true));
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => [fbes_keep]hello[/fbes_keep]
                [1] => [fbes_remove]goodbye[/fbes_remove]
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => [fbes_keep]
                [1] => [fbes_remove]
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => hello
                [1] => goodbye
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => [/fbes_keep]
                [1] => [/fbes_remove]
            )

    )
    */
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
    // how many matches you have is here
    $count_of_matches = count($matches[0]);

    // to answer your comment question...get the 3 parts for match group 0
    $match_group = 0; // you also have a match_group 1
    // loop over them if you like // foreach ($matches[0] as $match_group=>$full_match) {

    // for now, loop over the match group 0's 3 outputs
    for ($i=1; $i<4; $i++) {
      echo $matches[$i][$match_group].', ';
    }
    // [fbes_keep], hello, [/fbes_keep], 

    // or access them directly
    echo "{$matches[1][0]}, {$matches[2][0]}, {$matches[3][0]}";
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
    // here is the full, double loop grabbing all of them
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match_group=>$full_match) {
      for ($i=1; $i<4; $i++) {
        echo $matches[$i][$match_group].', ';
      }
      echo '<br>';
    }

    /* yielding
    [fbes_keep], hello, [/fbes_keep],
    [fbes_remove], goodbye, [/fbes_remove],
    */
```

Comment: How would I go through the fragments one at a time, though? For example, if I wanted to loop over them, where the loop gets `[fbes_keep]`, `hello`, `[/fbes_keep]`, and so on, one at a time.

Comment: i'm updating my answer with the answer to that.

Comment: You could also use PREG_PATTERN_ORDER with http://php.net/preg_match_all to group all the match groups.  i assumed you would probably want all of the "hello" and "goodbye" pieces together, but it's really up to how you plan to use them.