# Replacing string except certain parts

Tags: php

I'm writing a PHP app, and I have an input string in the form

```
Hello world. Hello [fbes_keep]world[/fbes_keep].
```

And a new string in the form

```
Hallo welt. Hello.
```

What I want it for the input string to be replaced by the new string, *except* the parts in the `[fbes_keep]` tags, so the output is

```
Hallo welt. Hello [fbes_keep]world[/fbes_keep].
```

My current approach involves using the [finediff library](http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php) but overriding the delete opcodes to look for the `fbes` tags. I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389509/regex-split-position-before-and-after-match) about this yesterday, but I feel I may have run into the XY problem. **Is there a better way?**

**Edit:** [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3b018eab308eea686044421f51b64888) containing current (non-functional) code and real-world test case.

Comment: So you want to delete any content between `[fbes_keep]` tag? Does this tag names can be changed or it's constant?

Comment: @Justinas I want the output string to be the new string, except the parts between the `[fbes_keep]` tags, which should be copied from the old string (in my example, the `world` is kept, even though it's not in the new string, because it's in the `[fbes_keep]` tags). And yes, the tag name stays the same.

Comment: Use `preg_replace("/.*(\[fbes_keep\].*)/", $newStr."$1", $str)`

Comment: @Mohammad and what does it do?

Comment: @karacsi_maci What he want. Replace everything before `[fbes_keep]` with new string.

Comment: @Mohammad There can be multiple `[fbes_keeps]` in the string and the `[fbes_keep]...[/fbes_keep]` can have contents which also need to be in, but from the old string.

Comment: @Mohammad Also, it's entirely possible that there are no `[fbes_keep]`s in the input at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the most elegant way how do I did it, but I've tested it, and it do the job:

```
$expression = 'world';
$newExpression = 'welt';
$str = 'Hello world. Hello [fbes_keep]world[/fbes_keep]. Here are some other world, and [fbes_keep]other[/fbes_keep] word in fbes.';
$pattern = '/\[fbes_keep\].*?\[\/fbes_keep\]/i';
$fbKepps = [];
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $fbKepps);
$others = preg_split($pattern, $str);
$result = '';
$i = 0;
foreach ($others as $other) {
    $result .= preg_replace('/' . addslashes($expression) . '/', $newExpression, $other);
    $i++;
    if ($i < count($others)) {
        $result .= $fbKepps[0][$i - 1];
    }

}
echo $result;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Hello welt. Hello [fbes_keep]world[/fbes_keep]. Here are some other welt, and [fbes_keep]other[/fbes_keep] word in fbes.
```

My ideia is to split the string by `[fbes_keep]...[/fbes_keep]`, but before store them in an array. Then iterate through all the rest, change the `world` to `welt` then concat the next `fbes_keep` and so on...

It keeps everything wher `[fbes_keep]anything[/fbes_keep]` and there are multiple fbes_keep can be in string with other words too.

Comment: The thing is, it's not quite as simple as just changing the "world" to "welt". In the real world the inputs are long strings that need to be changed in their entirety. Please see the linked test cases.

Comment: _In the real world the inputs are long strings_ And? What is the problem. `$expression` could be a long string, as `$newExpression`. I did it what you asked exactly.

Comment: Forgive me, I worded it poorly. My point is, I don't see the difference between `$expression` and `$str`. Your example just replaces `world` with `welt` everywhere except in the `fbes` tags. My use case is not as simple as just one word.

Comment: But as I sad, you can use long expressions. For example, you can use `$expression='Here are some other world';` and $newExpression = `'There is some other thing';` The `$str` is the whole text (subject), `$expression` is what you want to replace (from),  `$newExpression` is the `repleacement` (to). Try it.

Comment: Could `$str` and `$expression` be the same thing? I want to copy over the entire string (minus the fbes'd bits), not just replace some small parts.